# Network fees and light-wallet options

Tags: transaction-fees, light-wallet

I am new to Monero but not crypto in general. A couple of questions -

1. When I sent my XMR from the exchange to my wallet I was surprised at the high mining fee (0.05 XMR!) Is this normal?
2. I run a full Monero (GUI) node which is very demanding and I am not looking to mine. Are there any trusted light-wallets for Monero? Can you recommend any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *(A speculative answer):* Yes, it seems that most exchanges have 0.05 XMR withdrawal fee. Monero transaction fees are quite high but not *that high*. Perhaps the exchanges try to offset the cost of Monero integration. Remember that XMR has no common code with BTC and its' clones, so it must have been more costly to integrate than another BTC fork/spinoff. Hopefully the fees will drop with growing Monero popularity.
2. You may try Monerujo for Android, or the CLI version which is not resource-demanding. There are also online wallets but I'm not in a position to point you to any of them. Only reminding you to be careful here, because with online wallet you should **always assume that someone else has access to your funds**.